# OnGetAbc and OnPostABC reinitialize class and loses all mode data in ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

ASP.NET Core razor page with multiple drop downs and every drop down is in different form. Or you can say I have multiple forms in my razor page when I submit one form page initializes its constructor and I lost model with `BindProperty`.

How can I maintain the page data when user submits the form?

Comment: Hi @Talha Talha, welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a minimal and reproducible code to us. Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example